# Incrementing a div data value and then setting it back again in coffescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, coffeescript

I have this coffeescript code:

```
 $(document).ready ->
    setInterval refresh_table, 1000

 refresh_table = ->
    $.ajax 
      url: "/ac_units/refresh_table"
      format: "js"
      type: "POST"
      data: { pointer:$('#pointer').data('pointer'), ideal:$('#ideal').val() ,      current:$('#current').val() }
```

This code works.

I want to add features to this code. 
        1) I would like to increment the pointer before its sent to the server above
        2) I would like to set the updated pointer value to the div's data
        3) I would like to send the updated pointer to the server

I tried the following approach to accomplish the above features:

```
$(document).ready ->
  setInterval refresh_table, 1000

refresh_table = ->
  a = $("#pointer").data("pointer")
  $("#pointer").data "pointer", a++
  $.ajax
url: "/XXX/refresh_table"
format: "js"
type: "POST"
data: { pointer:$('#pointer').data('pointer'), abc:$('#abc').val() , efg:$('#efg').val() }
```

But this did not work.
No incrementing takes place.
Here is some output from my console:

```
 Processing by XXXController#refresh_table as */*
 Parameters: {"pointer"=>"0", "abc"=>"73", "efg"=>"79"}
 Received params = {"pointer"=>"0", "abc"=>"73", "efg"=>"79", "controller"=>"xxx", "action"=>"refresh_table"}
 ptr = 0


 Started POST "/XXX/refresh_table" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-04 14:15:44 -0400
 Processing by XXXController#refresh_table as */*
 Parameters: {"pointer"=>"0", "abc"=>"73", "efg"=>"79"}
 Received params = {"pointer"=>"0", "abc"=>"73", "efg"=>"79", "controller"=>"xxx", "action"=>"refresh_table"}
 ptr = 0
```

What am I doing wrong ? WHy is the variable not being incremented? Can anyone suggest?

Thanks

---

Tried this code in response to an answer below:

```
 $(document).ready ->
    setInterval refresh_table, 1000

 refresh_table = ->
    a = $("#pointer").data("pointer")
    x = ++a
    $("#pointer").data "pointer", x
    $.ajax 
      url: "/ac_units/refresh_table"
      format: "js"
      type: "POST"
      data: { pointer:x, ideal:$('#ideal').val() , current:$('#current').val() }
```

But the pointer value is still always 0

Comment: There's no reason to introduce `x`, I was just using that to demonstrate the problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `a++`. You need either `++a` or simply `a + 1`.

`a++` evaluates to the value of `a` before being incremented, so that's what you're setting as the "new" `data` attribute.

Simply...

```
a = 1
x = a++
console.log(a) # 2
console.log(x) # 1
```

This saves the value of `a` (which is 1) aside then increments `a` to 2, and then sets `x` to the *saved* value of `a`, which was `1`.

Basically, your code guarantees that the data attribute never changes because it always sets `pointer` back to the current value of `a` before it was incremented:

```
a = $("#pointer").data("pointer")
$("#pointer").data "pointer", a++
```

While this code correctly increments the attribute by setting it to the value of `a` *after* `a` is incremented.

```
a = $("#pointer").data("pointer")
$("#pointer").data "pointer", ++a
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. I updated my post after trying your suggestion. But my pointer is still always 0. It must be some other issue seems like.

Comment: No, it's really not. You're either not giving us all the data, or you're not correctly implementing this solution; the code you've given us is *guaranteed* to suffer from the problem I've outlined here. It's trivially easy to prove this to yourself: Drop your javascript console, and run `a = 1; alert(a++)` and you'll see `1`. Now try `a = 1; alert(++a)` and you'll see `2`. This is pretty straight forward.

Comment: I see. OK thanks a lot. I'll check the other parts of my code then. Seems like there might be issues there.